# Cannot remove specific polygons

Tags: modeling

Here is my first model
[image: Edit Mode]

I cannot figure it out how to remove "ears". I made something and these polys/edges/vertices become unselectable but still visible in object mode

[image: Object mode]

I just want to remove them to remake it completely

**UPD**
Here is how my model looks in solid shading
[image: Solid shader]

And when I select all via `A`
[image: Select all]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for noob question
Problem solved, I have made something definitely wrong :)

[image: My bug]